# Writing data to database: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java

I'm trying to write data to a database but i get the following error and obviously don't know how to go about sorting it out, still a newbie.

i get the following error when i run the code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javaapplication1.Registration.SaveRecord(Registration.java:65)
at javaapplication1.Registration.BtnRegActionPerformed(Registration.java:242)
at javaapplication1.Registration.access$300(Registration.java:21)
at javaapplication1.Registration$4.actionPerformed(Registration.java:209)
```

This is my code:

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Registration extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private static Statement st;
private static ResultSet rs;
private static Connection conn;
private static String selTable;



    public Registration() {
        initComponents();
    }

   public void CreateResultSet(){
    try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

     try{
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:cb1");
         st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

    String sql = "Insert into Users(Title,FName,SName,IDNO,PAddress,EAddress,Username,Password) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    st.execute(sql);
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
}
catch(SQLException ex){
  Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
}

    }

 public void SaveRecord (){

 try {

          rs.moveToInsertRow();

          rs.updateString("Title",txtTitle.getText());
          rs.updateString("FName",txtName.getText());
          rs.updateString("SName",txtSname.getText());
          rs.updateString("IDNO",txtID.getText());
          rs.updateString("PAddress",txtPA.getText());
          rs.updateString("EAddress",txtE.getText());
          rs.updateString("Username",txtUsern.getText());
          rs.updateString("Password",txtPass.getText());


          rs.insertRow();   

 } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registration Complete");

}

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtSname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtID = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtPA = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtE = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtUsern = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtPass = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        BtnReg = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txtTitle = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("Name");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
        jLabel1.setBounds(40, 70, 40, 15);

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel2.setText("Surname");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
        jLabel2.setBounds(40, 100, 50, 15);

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel3.setText("ID Number");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel3);
        jLabel3.setBounds(40, 140, 60, 15);

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel4.setText("Physical Address");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel4);
        jLabel4.setBounds(30, 180, 90, 15);
        getContentPane().add(txtName);
        txtName.setBounds(130, 70, 100, 20);

        txtSname.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtSnameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(txtSname);
        txtSname.setBounds(130, 100, 100, 30);
        getContentPane().add(txtID);
        txtID.setBounds(130, 140, 190, 30);
        getContentPane().add(txtPA);
        txtPA.setBounds(130, 180, 250, 30);

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel5.setText("Title");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel5);
        jLabel5.setBounds(40, 40, 40, 15);

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel6.setText("Email Address");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel6);
        jLabel6.setBounds(30, 220, 80, 15);

        txtE.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtEActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(txtE);
        txtE.setBounds(130, 220, 160, 30);

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel7.setText("Username");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel7);
        jLabel7.setBounds(30, 270, 70, 15);
        getContentPane().add(txtUsern);
        txtUsern.setBounds(130, 270, 130, 30);

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel8.setText("Password");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel8);
        jLabel8.setBounds(30, 310, 60, 15);

        txtPass.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtPassActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(txtPass);
        txtPass.setBounds(130, 310, 130, 30);

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel10.setText("Registration");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel10);
        jLabel10.setBounds(50, 0, 170, 30);

        BtnReg.setText("Submit");
        BtnReg.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BtnRegActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(BtnReg);
        BtnReg.setBounds(70, 350, 65, 23);

        jButton2.setText("Cancel");
        getContentPane().add(jButton2);
        jButton2.setBounds(170, 350, 65, 23);
        getContentPane().add(txtTitle);
        txtTitle.setBounds(130, 40, 140, 20);

        jLabel9.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Boosta\\Pictures\\keyboard-register.jpg")); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setText("jLabel9");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel9);
        jLabel9.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txtSnameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void txtEActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void txtPassActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    private void BtnRegActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
       SaveRecord();
        CreateResultSet();

    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Registration().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton BtnReg;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtE;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtID;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtPA;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtPass;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtSname;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtTitle;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtUsern;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception is being thrown because something was not initialized. In your case, the window is being initialized, but the program is getting hung up in the SaveRecord() method.

While txtTitle does exist, nowhere in the program is txtTitle's text set. When the method calls txtTitle.getText(), txtTitle throws your exception because txtTitle's text is null.

Use the user input to set the text, or for a bomb-proof solution (maybe not the correct one), initialize txtTitle's text to an empty string ("")

Don't forget about the rest of the variables in the SaveRecord method, either!